# AsyncStorage don't save the change state - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I followed the documentation sample about AsyncStorage:

[React Native - AsyncStorage docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

. so, I implemented my code:

`var STORAGE_KEY = '@AsyncStorageExample:key';`

and i define my class with this functions:

I have a initial state:

```
state={
  defineValor: 0,
};
```

and the `componentDidMount` function and `_loadInitialState`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._loadInitialState().done();
};

_loadInitialState = async () => {
  try {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
    if (value !== null){
      this.setState({defineValor: value});
      alert('Recovered selection from disk: ' + value);
    } else {
      alert('Initialized with no selection on disk.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
  }
};
```

So i made a function to change the state with AsyncStorage, as well as in the documentation:

```
changeState = () => {
  this.setState ({
    defineValor: 1
  });
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, this.state.defineValor);
    alert('Saved selection to disk: ' + this.state.defineValor);
  } catch (error) {
    alert('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
  }
};
```

So, when i open the app, all the process run, alert "Initialized with no selection on disk" and when i call my function `changeState` , he's alert "Saved selection to disk: 1". But when i close de app and reopen, the state was not saved, and he's alert "Initialized with no selection on disk.". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably AsyncStorage sets the value before defineValor state is updated. setState has a callback function do the AsyncStorage setItem in that callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` has a callback do the `AsyncStorage.setItem` in that callback.
Also AsyncStorage accepts only **string** as value

```
this.setState({ defineValor: string }, () => {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, this.state.defineValor);
    alert('Saved selection to disk: ' + this.state.defineValor);
  } catch (error) {
    alert('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. But i really tried it, and dosen't work yet. Do you have an other idea?

Comment: AsyncStorage accepts value as **string** , you are trying to set number right. Try setting a string value

Comment: Happy to help :)